# Emacs org-mode minted export with #+ATTR_LATEX

Tags: emacs, minted

When I try to export a file like this:

```
#+LaTeX_CLASS: tufte

#+ATTR_LaTeX: :float t :options label={test}
#+begin_src c
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
#+end_src
```

The `options` attribute is ignored (it does not go the the generated `tex` file) and only the default options are passed:

```
\begin{listing}[H]
\begin{minted}[frame=lines, linenos=true]{c}
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\end{listing}
```

Any idea why? My org version is 8.2.7c.

Edit: my setup for this:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (require 'ox-latex)
  (require 'org-latex)
  (add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "minted"))

  (setq org-latex-listings 'minted)

  (setq org-latex-minted-options
        '(("frame" "lines") ("linenos=true")))

  (setq org-latex-pdf-process (list "latexmk -pdf %f"))
#+end_src


** Tufte
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
               `("tufte"
                 "\\documentclass{tufte-handout}"
                 ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
                 ("\\subsection{%s}" "\\newpage" "\\subsection*{%s}" "\\newpage")
                 ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
                 ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
                 ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))
               )
#+end_src
```

Comment: What is your `org-mode` set-up for the `tufte` class etc.?

Comment: @AndrewSwann I have updated the question.

Comment: Lucas so far the only classes it identifies, are: `report` `book` `article`. And I assume there's no way you could work around that? I compiled the above, with all them classes. And everything seemed good to me. .. as of today, the file `ox-latex` is the one you should blame. I haven't had time to change it directly, as it requires some time to compile. I also have to deal with the fact, not to be oblivious to the last touch, these files undergo, to understandable compressing measures, during compilation. If I were you, since you particularly need that class, ...

Comment: I'd request such a feature. Or work around with the `tex` file, that `report`, `book`, and `article` compile with `C-c C-e l l`

Comment: @doed even with the article, book or report classes the exported code goes without the label. what i've been doing is exporting the file to tex as you mentioned and then going one listing at a time and adapting.

Answer (score 4):

Lucas, I myself don't use `org-mode`, but if I were to have, as an example, the first MWE in your question, and add `#+NAME`, to the following line after `#+ATTR_LaTeX:` subsequently followed by whatever name, you want to reference the label to, the document compiles fine, as long as one of the three classes, that is, `report`, `book` or `article` are specified in `#+LaTeX_CLASS`, instead of `tufte`.

EDIT: Second edit. Yes Lucas. The options, the environment, the non-environment, and everything in between, gets passed along, once the options, the environment, the non-environment, and everything in between is loaded by the initialization file.

So, to get the minted options, the right default options, and the right environment to get the options, the initialization file needs to have at least:

```
  (setq org-latex-listings 'minted)
  (setq org-latex-minted-options
     '(("frame" "lines") ("linenos=true")))
```

So that gives you:

```
  \begin{listing}[H]
  \begin{minted}[frame=lines,linenos=true]{c}
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  \end{minted}
  \label{ref:sourC}
  \end{listing}
```

So for example:

```
  #+LaTeX_CLASS: book

  #+ATTR_LaTeX: :float t :options label={test}
  #+NAME: ref:source 
  #+begin_src c
      #include <iostream>
      using namespace std;

      int main() {
          cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
          return 0;
      }


  #+end_src
```

Gives you a `tex` file with the following lines:

```
  \begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{verbatim}
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  \end{verbatim}\label{ref:source}

  \end{figure}
```

Comment: However that is not what I need :( It should "caption" a minted source code, which it doesn't.

Comment: Lucas, I honestly can't believe you are still stuck on the issue. Lucas. How would you expect to have the options, let alone the environment, unless it is loaded in the init file to start with... that's like saying what's wrong with my emacs. let me update the answer.

Comment: doed, perfect. everything you said is correct. however, the minted source should have a caption in it, and that cannot go on the config file, as the caption is not constant. that is the problem. my config generates the correct code apart from this...

Comment: Lucas, then just add a `#+CAPTION: caption`

Comment: that does not work. the minted label, or any other option passed in the options command js ignored

Comment: Lucas, ha, both `\label` and caption are after the environment. May I suggest you, to ask a new question? If caption is a problem (according to you), you never mentioned it as such, in your question. To the contrary, you were concerned about a label. So the label's culprit was found, and all of a sudden is the caption. And I still think, if it was not a problem, namely the caption, it should have been mentioned either way, in the original question.

Comment: It is anything that should go in the OPTIONS of the `#+ATTR_LATEX` command that gets ignored. I'm just using those as an example. If you remove from the config the linenos option and add in the .org file itself it also does not go. The question clearly states that: "The options attribute is ignored (it does not go the the generated tex file) and only the default options are passed:"

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of `org-latex-listings`, you also need to configure `org-latex-pdf-process` to pass the `-shell-escape` option. The following works for me:

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
      (mapcar
       (lambda (s)
         (replace-regexp-in-string "%latex " "%latex -shell-escape " s))
       org-latex-pdf-process))
```